# Ошибки валидации CSS

Tags: html, css

При проверки CSS на ошибки возникла проблема с валидацией -по неизвестной причине свойства flexbox не проходят проверку по стандарту CSS3 и возникают следующие ошибки

> 66    .block  Value Error : display flex is not a display value : flex
>   flex
>
> 67    .block  Property flex-direction doesn't exist : column column
>
> 68    .block  Property justify-content doesn't exist : center center
>
> 69    .block  Property align-items doesn't exist : center center

Ниже приведен код, который не проходит валидацию по CSS3

```
.block{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    margin:20px 0;
}
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Выбросьте этот валидатор и пишите свой код как вам это удобно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Единственные ошибки которые я вижу, это отсутствие пробелов после : после align-items и margin. Также можно добавить вендорные префиксы:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
margin: 20px 0;
```

Если проблема сохранилась, напишите, пожалуйста, какой именно валидатор ее выдает

Comment: Виталий, к сожалению, Ваши советы не помогли решить проблемы валидации. Использую http://www.css-validator.org/validator Profile :CSS3

Comment: Не знаю, где вы откопали этот валидатор. Вот W3C валидатор показывает что ошибок нету https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Понял. Спасибо Вам за помощь!

Comment: Если проблема решена, можете отметить мой ответ как правильный)

Comment: Как это сделать ?

Comment: Нажмите на галочку возле моего ответа)